# Copy Certain Cells from Selected Row

Tags: excel, vba

I currently have some lines written that highlight and select the entire row that I have clicked on. I would like to click a button that copies specific cells in the row that I have selected shown in ("B7")'s value. Below is written to copy the entire row, but I want specific columns in that row (D, E, F, H, I, K, L, M, N). So if I click on row 23, I want to copy the cells D23, E23, F23, H23... etc)

```
Sub Card_Trailer()
With Sheet2
TrailerRow = .Range("B7").Value
.Range(TrailerRow & ":" & TrailerRow).EntireRow.Copy

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```vb
Sub Card_Trailer()
    Dim rw As Range
    Set rw = Sheet2.Rows(Sheet2.Range("B7").Value)  'using a row# from a cell
    'Set rw = Selection.Cells(1).EnrireRow          'or get the currently-selected row
    rw.Range("D1,E1,F1,H1,I1,K1,L1,M1,N1").Copy  'range address is *relative* to rw
End Sub
```

Comment: Tim, that works wonderfully. Now may I ask you how I should approach the next issue. Id like for these new copied cells to appear in a shape that is on another sheet. Then If I run the macro again, a new shape is formed, and the new set of copied cells paste into that shape.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "appear in a shape"   Can you add a screenshot?

Comment: I just posted a better explanation. It turns out I dont need the copy command because I need the values of the cells in the row to "update" or reflect changes when made in the list on the other sheet. My new question is posted if you would like to look. You really helped me out thanks!